# IBus not working in Cinnamon

Tags: keyboard-layout, cinnamon, ibus

I have configured these 3 languages in IBus while I was using Gnome desktop-- **English (US)**, **Bengali (Avro-Phonetic)** and **Hindi (KaGaPa phonetic)**. Recently I have installed Cinnamon and I haven't found any settings related to IBus in the Cinnamon control centre (Settings page) although I have `ibus-avro` and `ibus-m17n` installed. Most of the posts I have seen till now related to this issue are outdated and therefore cannot be used.

Any idea how can this issue be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While IBus is integrated into GNOME settings to a large extent, I would think that you need to use *IBus Preferences* to handle your input languages in case of Cinnamon. It should be available in the menus somewhere, or you can also start it via the terminal command

```
ibus-setup
```

In *IBus preferences* enable the **Show icon on system tray** checkbox:
[image]
If you still cannot see the IBus icon on the panel, open **Cinnamon settings**, go to the **Applets** section and enable the **System Tray** applet:
[image]

Comment: Oh yes, the IBus preferences window is available from the menu. Thanks for the suggestion. But now, even after enabling IBus, no language switcher is appearing on the desktop panel as was before on Gnome. Do I need to install any libraries to make it appear the panel?

Comment: @Puspam: There is a "Show icon on system tray" option in _IBus Preferences_. If that is checked, an icon ought to show up, at least if you have more than one items listed in the _Input Method_ tab.

Comment: I have tried that too, but still the same case.

Comment: @Puspam: Then you need help from someone who (unlike me) knows something about Cinnamon.

Comment: I have solved it. In Cinnamon, the system tray is an applet. I must have disabled it somehow. After enabling that applet the IBus icon is displayed on the panel. Again thanks for your answer, because I was successfully able to enable IBus.

Comment: @Puspam: Great! Please feel free to edit the answer with that additional info. Doing so might help others.